# Export SSL & TLS Registry Keys to XLSX

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, ssl, csv, tls

I'm currently looking to find out all SSL and TLS Registry value information on the system. I need help writing a script for powershell to look at a list of hosts that are on a csv/txt file then execute the following command saving the result in a csv/XLSX format having the computer name, SSL and TLS registry entry.

```
#Get computers from text file. 1 compute per line
Clear-Host
$myComputerList = 'ABC' #Get-Content C:\Servers.txt

#Loop Through Array
ForEach ($computer in $myComputerList) {
    #Execute a command on the computer
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
        #This is the command to execute
        #Grab the registry value you want and hold it in a variable
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\'
} #| Out-File -FilePath C:\Output.csv -Append
}
```

The above code is working as expected, but when i export that to the CSV/XLSX format the formation is not in a good way, it is something like below:

[image]

**Output** :

Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders
\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0

Name                           Property                 PSComputerName

---

Client                         DisabledByDefault : 0    ABC
Enabled           : 0
Server                         DisabledByDefault : 0    ABC
Enabled           : 0

```
Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders
\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0
```

Name                           Property                 PSComputerName

---

Client                         DisabledByDefault : 1    ABC
Enabled           :
4294967295
Server                         DisabledByDefault : 0    ABC
Enabled           :
4294967295

From the above output i don't want the entire Hive path, just need the SSL or the TLS in in the output.

Please help me to get the code as expected

**Thanks In Advance**

**Looking for the below Output**
[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: Looking for the output as attached in the question at the end.

Comment: Make sure that you import the CSV in the correct way i.e. in terms of delimiters (tabs or spaces) or fixed width spacing. If you do this right, everything should at least be in it own cell. I suspect you aren

Comment: ...I suspect you aren't actually exporting csv (comma separated values) but simply text. If that's the case, use consecutive spaces as delimiters. This way everything should at least be in its own cell, although spread all over the place. You can then code a "clean up" macro in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open file from within Excel
2. Use the text import wizard to split the text into columns
   (treat consecutive spaces and/or tabs treated as one)
3. If the wizard doesn't pop up, and imports everything into one
   column, select column, then click data > Text to columns
4. OR Data > From Text (opens the data as a **data source**, ie. linked to csv
   file remains in tact, can be refreshed on schedule, on open or manually)
5. On a new sheet, extract and reformat the data as you'd like, using
   either Excel formulas or VBA code (VBA could reformat the data in-place on the same sheet, deleting the unnecessary rows and cells etc. Using the Excel formula option together with the **data source** import could provide a flexible and easy way to summarise the data, especially if the data changes often

If you are lucky there is a fixed pattern in the imported data, say every 10th row contains a computer name in column G, then in the new sheet you can cherry pick the computer names from the rows, starting in sheet2 cell G1 and dragging this formula down:

```
=INDEX(sheet1!$G:$G,(ROW()-1)*10+1
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` objects returned by `Get-ChildItem` use custom formatting to appear more readable in the console (This formatting is defined in `$PSHome\Registry.format.ps1xml`).

Copy some of the formatting commands and output it into a real CSV:

```
ForEach ($computer in $myComputerList) {
    #Execute a command on the computer
    Invoke-Command $computer {
        Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\' |
            Select PSParentPath,PSChildName,@{l='Properties';e={
                (Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $_.PSPath |
                    Select * -Exclude PSPath,PSParentPath,PSChildName,PSDrive,PsProvider |
                    Format-List | Out-String | Sort).Trim()
            }}
    } | select PSComputerName,@{l='Name';e={$_.PSParentPath  -split '\\' | select -Last 1}},PSChildName,Properties | export-csv C:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Here's the output in excel (I had to expand the cells):

[image]

You'll have to copy the `Get-ChildItem` block for each protocol name

Comment: Wow. I had no idea PS was this powerful. I'm used to DOS style batch scripts lol. You lost me at @{l='Properties'...

Comment: If possible can you please help me with the the script for the TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 as well please

Comment: I got the output as expected thanks for the help

Comment: Can i get the output in two line as for SSL i need the Disabled and Enabled values in two line instead of in one line

Comment: @chandu do you need it in separate rows? It should already be in two-line format like in the screenshot. Also, if you got the output you needed, consider marking the question as answered

Answer (score -1):

You could also try and extract individual properties from the registry like this:

```
Get-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client' -name DisabledByDefault  | select-object -ExpandProperty DisabledByDefault
```

I don't have those registry entries in my registry, so can't verify if it will work 100%.